# CompletableFuture parameter thread safe modification

Tags: java, spring, completable-future

I have this test - which is currently green by the way:

```java
@Slf4j
public class CalculationTests {

    @Test
    void testParallelComputation() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            doIt(new CalculationDto(1, 2, 0));
        }
    }

    void doIt(CalculationDto calculationDto) {
        CompletableFuture<CalculationDto> calculationDtoCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> {
                    calculationDto.setResult(calculationDto.a + calculationDto.b); // a = 1, b = 2 -> result = 3
                    return calculationDto;
                })
                .thenApply(calculationDto1 -> {
                    calculationDto.setA(2); // a = 2, result = 3
                    calculationDto.setB(calculationDto1.getResult()); // b = 3
                    log.error("res 1");
                    return calculationDto;
                }).thenApply(calculationDto2 -> {
                    calculationDto.setResult(calculationDto2.a + calculationDto2.b); // result = 2 + 3 = 5
                    log.error("res 2");
                    return calculationDto;
                });

        assertThat(calculationDtoCompletableFuture.join().getResult()).isEqualTo(5);
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class CalculationDto {
        private Integer a;
        private Integer b;
        private Integer result;

    }
}
```

I want to simulate a chain of calculations on a `DTO`.
In the real world, this `DTO` comes from a MVC `Controller` sent via `POST`. Then it is processed with various tasks and sent back to the client.

So my question (in addition to the green test) is:

Is this the right way to modify a DTO within a chain of `CompletableFuture` in a thread safe manner?

**EDIT:**

Even if i change the test the following the test is green. In this variation i return the current lambda parameter from the `thenApply` being `calculationDto1` and `calculationDto2`.

The log is always in this order:

res1

res2

res3

```java
void doIt(CalculationDto calculationDto) {
        CompletableFuture<CalculationDto> calculationDtoCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> {
                    calculationDto.setResult(calculationDto.a + calculationDto.b); // a = 1, b = 2 -> result = 3
                    log.error("res 1");
                    return calculationDto;
                })
                .thenApply(calculationDto1 -> {
                    calculationDto1.setA(2); // a = 2, result = 3
                    calculationDto1.setB(calculationDto1.getResult()); // b = 3
                    log.error("res 2");
                    return calculationDto1;
                }).thenApply(calculationDto2 -> {
                    calculationDto2.setResult(calculationDto2.a + calculationDto2.b); // result = 2 + 3 = 5
                    log.error("res 3");
                    return calculationDto2;
                });

        assertThat(calculationDtoCompletableFuture.join().getResult()).isEqualTo(5);
    }
```

Comment: The `then` in thenApply means that all previous tasks must have finished. In order to have the chance to make the test Red you need a second concurrent CompletableFuture.

Comment: BTW, ich glaube wir haben schon mal miteinander gearbeitet, wie klein die Welt doch ist....

Comment: @Grim Ok? Das wäre ja lustig. Wo denn? An der THD? Hast du auch mit Java zu tun?

Comment: Hm, glaub der hieß doch Thomas Lange. Sorry.

Comment: What is the point of this `thenApply` chain? You could write all statements in one `Runnable` instead. And why do you think it matters which variable (captured or lambda parameter) you use when all of them contain exactly the same object reference?

Comment: My thoughts about `thenApply` was like an assembly line. There are several rules to follow (each in a `thenApply`). These rules lead to modification of my calculation dto. As example: Rule1: I go to a Jira API and query for the project´s country. If this country != Deutschland i set the betterment tax to 0% ... and so on. So my concern was/is if it is safe to use this calculation dto (in details its setter) to change properties in various `thenApply` branches. In other words: Can it be possible that multiple `thenApply` rules access a setter at the same time - leaving it corrupted.